# Android Biometric Security API

Tags: android, security, api

I have a great idea for a biometric security app and some secure transactions, but i have no idea how to use a biometric api, if it exists. Anyone knows anything about any biometric api? Any ideas how to develop one?

I would appreciate any kind of help or information. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of biometrics? OpenCV can help you do this using the camera...

http://opencv.org/android

Comment: I want to use biometrics in my app like face recognition using the camera to make secure transactions.

Have you worked with OpenCV before? I'm new in this, and i have no much experience in Android.

Thanks for the reply, it was very helpful.

Comment: @brachialste: sorry, have not used OpenCV for biometrics, and never used it on Android either.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is a good tool to make facial recognition. You can use it to communicate with embedded cameras, detect faces, and compare two faces. But if you need a better SDK you can use Neurotechnology or a free webservice supplied by [SkyBiometrics](http://www.skybiometry.com/)

My advice is if you don`t have much time to work with OpenCV and improve it algorithms / study it to use correctly, you can use SkyBiometrics that have a free usage and could work fine with your application if you have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't have experience working with a biometric API for Android. From what I've read and heard from developers, OpenCV seems like something you should opt for, especially since you don't have experience of it either.

This information might be of help if you want to use the fingerprint ID feature of the phone:
Android fingerprint API launched with Android 6.0 will offer a bevy of useful features to integrate new authentication technology for app developers with the apps. To implement this API in your new Android app you need to get the Android SDK first. The SDK Manager then will allow you to download the SDK platform for Android 6.0 and introduce necessary steps. As part of the launching process, Android has also come up with new sample to demonstrate and guide the developers in integrating the API with the fingerprint readers in various devices.

Beating the so called security concerns over the use of fingerprint technology in mobile transaction Android has revealed how the new API offers protective measures for maintaining privacy. The new API as revealed will protect the critical fingerprint features by keeping them in the secure device hardware.
Android also expressed future plans to come with measures that can help identifying fingerprint of users just before allowing access to critical resources and data. These identification measures would help protecting against all malicious intrusions and tampered applications by ensuring cryptographic level security for all types of transactions and access to offline data and online interactions. This hardware level protection of critical data offers full proof protection against all malicious actions and security threats making it safe for the users to use their fingerprints.

Source:

[Android Fingerprint API for App Developers](http://blog.m2sys.com/biometric-hardware/android-fingerprint-api-for-app-developers/)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You shouldn't base your answer on a link: if it changes or the site goes offline, your answer becomes useless. Instead, use the info on the site to build your answer and post the link as reference only. Thanks.