# Voice authentication in Android app

Tags: android, voice-recognition, voice

Is it possible to integrate voice authentication into my app? I'm not interested in recognising voice commands - rather I am interested in detecting *who* is speaking. I know Lollipop had a 'Trusted Voice' screen unlock system a while ago but I can't see it anymore on my version of Android (6.0.1). If it still exists, is it possible to use this 'Trusted Voice' authentication method in my app?

Is voice authentication possible using the standard Android API - or is a third party library required?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Biometric Security API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172886/android-biometric-security-api)

Comment: You have to use third party library. There is a good one from Microsoft, you can also find offline library.